# Lightbox (videobox.js; mootools library) not working in Firefox for both Mac OS X and Windows

Tags: jquery, firefox, lightbox

First off, thanks for any help with this.

I have jCarousel sliders setup that has users click thumbnails to get a pop up video box (the pop up videobox is done using a script called videobox.js found here: http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/). It works fine in all other browsers, but clicking one of the first three thumbnails on the horizontal slider in Firefox opens the video in a new window and/or has a broken link (if you scroll to the next three thumbnails, videobox works correctly oddly enough). The two photos of the doctors (Dr. Bulger, Dr. Renaud) at the top of the page are working correctly which make me think there is a conflict with the two scripts (jsCarousel.js and videobox.js). Again, I only have this issue using Firefox. Thoughts?

Here is the site with the sliders (horz and vert): http://southwest.dogbark.com/

**JS Code in the source code**

```js
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#carouselv').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); },   autoscroll: false, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 4, orientation: 'v' });
jQuery('#carouselh').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: false, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 6, orientation: 'h' });
jQuery('#carouselhAuto').jsCarousel({ onthumbnailclick: function(src) { alert(src); }, autoscroll: false, masked: true, itemstodisplay: 6, orientation: 'h' });

    });
```